# Hyper-V DC VM time keeps reverting after resync

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2016, time-synchronization

I have a domain controller running Windows Server 2016 in Hyper-V on a Windows Server 2016 Host. **My time is off by 9 minutes.** I've configured the following command to force custom NTP servers to be used:

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"0.us.pool.ntp.org 1.us.pool.ntp.org 2.us.pool.nt
p.org 3.us.pool.ntp.org" /syncfromflags:MANUAL /reliable:yes

w32tm /resync /rediscover
```

As soon as I use the resync command my time changes to the correct time, then after a few short seconds it reverts back to the wrong time of +9 minutes.

Here is the output of a **query peers**:

```
#Peers: 4

Peer: 0.us.pool.ntp.org
State: Active
Time Remaining: 0.0000000s
Mode: 1 (Symmetric Active)
Stratum: 2 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
PeerPoll Interval: 6 (64s)
HostPoll Interval: 6 (64s)

Peer: 1.us.pool.ntp.org
State: Active
Time Remaining: 0.0000000s
Mode: 1 (Symmetric Active)
Stratum: 2 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
PeerPoll Interval: 6 (64s)
HostPoll Interval: 6 (64s)

Peer: 3.us.pool.ntp.org
State: Active
Time Remaining: 0.0000000s
Mode: 1 (Symmetric Active)
Stratum: 3 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
PeerPoll Interval: 6 (64s)
HostPoll Interval: 6 (64s)

Peer: 2.us.pool.ntp.org
State: Active
Time Remaining: 0.0000000s
Mode: 1 (Symmetric Active)
Stratum: 3 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
PeerPoll Interval: 6 (64s)
HostPoll Interval: 6 (64s)
```

Here is the output of a **query configuration**:

```
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 5 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 6 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 7 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 100 (Local)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 3600 (Local)
Type: NTP (Local)
NtpServer: 0.us.pool.ntp.org 1.us.pool.ntp.org 2.us.pool.ntp.org 3.us.pool.ntp.org (Local)

NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)

VMICTimeProvider (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
```

Here is the output of a **query peers on the Host**:

```
#Peers: 1

Peer: <dc>.<domain>.local
State: Active
Time Remaining: 116.5376093s
Mode: 3 (Client)
Stratum: 3 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
PeerPoll Interval: 10 (1024s)
HostPoll Interval: 10 (1024s)
PS <user> w32tm /query /status
Leap Indicator: 0(no warning)
Stratum: 4 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
Precision: -6 (15.625ms per tick)
Root Delay: 0.0004871s
Root Dispersion: 10.0527505s
ReferenceId: 0xC0A80116 (source IP:  192.168.1.22)
Last Successful Sync Time: 7/13/2019 9:16:13 AM
Source: <dc>.<domain>.local
Poll Interval: 10 (1024s)
```

No matter what I do the time keeps reverting on the DC which makes all of the workstations have wrong times as well.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Is the Time synchronization Integration Service enabled (checked) in the settings of the VM? If so, uncheck it.

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: Sometimes it is also an empty bios Batterie xD and or the host which has a timedrift